# calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\left ( \ln(n^2 +1) -2\ln(n)\sqrt[n]{\ln(n)}\right )$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

As above, I have to calculate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\left  (  \ln(n^2 +1) -2\ln(n) \sqrt[n]{\ln(n)} \right )$$I tried to multiply it by $$ \frac{\left  (  \ln(n^2 +1) +2\ln(n)\sqrt[n]{\ln(n)}\right )}{\left  (  \ln(n^2 +1) +2\ln(n)\sqrt[n]{\ln(n)}\right )}$$ so that it is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n \frac{\left  (  \ln^2(n^2 +1) -2\ln^2 (n) \sqrt[\frac{1}{2}n]{\ln(n)} \right )}{\left  (  \ln(n^2 +1) +2\ln(n)\sqrt[n]{\ln(n)}\right )},$$but it is not so easy to play with (first glance says that it goes to infinity), nevertheless, can somebody take a closer look at this and suggest something, please? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following expansions yield readily an equivalent, hence the limit:

- $\ln(n^2+1)=2\log(n)+\log\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)=2\log(n)+o\left(\frac1n\right)$.
- $\sqrt[n]{\log n}=\exp\left(\frac1n\log\log n\right)=1+\frac1n\log(\log n)+o\left(\frac1n\right)$.